# CouchDB for Android Uses

Tags: android, database, realm, couchbase-lite, nosql

I had a nosql server for the application backend and json is coming from that server through Retrofit.

now i want to store the Json for the offline use, can i use that json to store in couchdb database.

Json structure can be

```
player -|
        | id
        | name -|
                | firstname
                | lastname
```

and then i want to search through firstname

Can i use couchbase-lite for that in android

or is there any other good alternative solution for that :- 
note :- it is a complex json so I can not covert it into POJO again otherwise I will use the Realm for this.

Comment: please explain properly !

Comment: You'll need to get it into some kind of POJO to store it in RealmObjects, because RealmObject is a class with properties/getters/setters

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do this.  If your JSON is in JSONString

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  // Usually you only need one instance of this per app.
try {
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(JSONString, Map.class);
    Document document = db.createDocument();
    document.putProperties(map);
} catch (IOException | CouchbaseLiteException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

ObjectMapper comes from the Jackson JSON library.  Currently Couchbase Lite uses Jackson, so you're not adding any extra dependencies.

For queries, you use Views to flexibly create indexes via map/reduce functions.  You then build queries against the indexes you create.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to store "standard java objects" in document properties in `couchbase lite`. those are,

```
int/Integer
String
float/Float
Collections of the above (maps, lists, sets).
```

So even if you want to store `JsonObject` or `JsonArray`, then first of all you need to convert them in to `string` using `toString()` method and the store it in `couchbase`.

In that case it will be very inefficient for you to executing search queries etc.

So I think one way is by converting is to convert it into `poJo` and then use `couchbase` but as you have written

> it is a complex json so I can not covert it into POJO again otherwise
>   I will use the Realm for this.

I suggest to not to use `couchbase`.

Comment: This is not correct.  Couchbase Lite stores JSON, not a subset.  With Views and the map/reduce features querying can be easy and efficient.

Comment: Yes, it links through to a simple way to do this.  Similar to shown in my answer.  OP talks about storing JSON received as a string.  It's very easy.  Not sure what your criticism is.